# What is the conjugate of $\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3}{2}i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the conjugate of $\dfrac{1}{2}+ \dfrac{3}{2}i$?

Firstly, what is conjugation? And secondly, can you should the steps to doing this?

"$i$" is the imaginary unit.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2}i$

Comment: Google is your friend!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$.

Comment: What is conjugate? How did you arrive at this answer? :)

Comment: @David: It is the definition of conjugate.  Here is a reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate

Comment: What Joe said is of course correct. If you want a more geometric idea, you can think of it as reflection across the x-axis in the complex plane.

Comment: @David There is nowhere to arrive from, conjugation is just defined this way. period.